# Appropriate Texturing of Human Face

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I am working on a human being in Blender and I made the vertices for the face plus a general human skin material, according to a tutorial I watched.

My issue is, that certain shadows don't show and it isn't due to lighting, as far as I see. For instance, the area under the nose and the groove above the eyelid western people often have. I know that people often use pre-made face textures on their models through UV texturing, but I don't want that sort of realism in my models. Do I have to make the shadow myself with clever use of gradient textures or should I try to make harder edges in my models in order to get more distinct shadows? Do these suggestions even work?

[image]

(I know, the materials are dismal still, but at least I know how I would improve them =) )

Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: it's hard to answer since your picture is so dark.  Can't tell if there is geometry on the face or not, and it's almost completely in shadow.  Also, you mentioned that it's "not due to lighting" but shadows are all about light - not sure what you mean.  It would help to post the blend file, or at least a better image.

Comment: But even in a dark picture, you should be able to notice some more pronounced shadows. I do know that shadows come from light. I just describe, that I am not satisfied with the shadows on my biped. I shifted the sun and the shadows don't get any different. That's what I mean with that

Comment: Ok. Well, I still think it would help to provide either a wireframe view so the geometry of the face is visible, or upload the blend file itself.  My guess is that it'd be hard to get the clever gradients to be where you want them to be, and so making more defined geometry seems to be the right idea.